# Best books for an introduction to statistical data analysis?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, references

I bought this book:

[How to Measure Anything: Finding the Value of Intangibles in Business](http://rcm.amazon.com/e/cm?lt1=_blank&bc1=000000&IS2=1&bg1=FFFFFF&fc1=000000&lc1=0000FF&t=justibozon-20&o=1&p=8&l=as1&m=amazon&f=ifr&md=10FE9736YVPPT7A0FBG2&asins=0470539399)

and

[Head First Data Analysis: A Learner's Guide to Big Numbers, Statistics, and Good Decisions](http://rcm.amazon.com/e/cm?lt1=_blank&bc1=000000&IS2=1&bg1=FFFFFF&fc1=000000&lc1=0000FF&t=justibozon-20&o=1&p=8&l=as1&m=amazon&f=ifr&md=10FE9736YVPPT7A0FBG2&asins=0596153937)

What other books would you recommend?

Comment: Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/421/what-book-would-you-recommend-for-non-statistician

Comment: You tagged this as bayesian and machine-learning.  What kind of data analysis are you interested in?

Comment: Shane: Honestly, I don't really know yet. What kind of data analysis is there? Should I be posing this as yet another question for the site?

Comment: There are many kinds.  :)  Those are just two specific areas, so it seems odd for tags on such a general question.

Comment: @Justin If you don't know it yet, this question is too broad and vague. A nice thing to learn what a field contains, is to look on the tags of this sites and see what questions match with it. Also wikipedia and the books you bought can give you and idea of what you want (although the books maybe not name the field wherein they operate, more on the practical overall part)

Comment: @Peter Smit: Thanks I'll give that a shot.
@Shane: Thanks as well... I was trying to give some idea of context with my tags.

Beware the noobs!

Comment: @robin There are only 7 users able to vote for closing... so it can take a small while

Comment: @robin @peter: It isn't clear to me that it's an exact duplicate either.  Are you both referring to the one I linked above or another one?

Comment: @shane I agree that it is not exact duplicate, but then it is too broad or not enough and the title is quite similar. In addition, my view is that someone asking for a book on stat.stack could at least say for what purpose and for what level.

Comment: @robin: I agree 100% with that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't find *How To Measure Anything*, nor *Head First*, particularly good.

*Statistics In Plain English* (Urdan) is a good starter book.

Once you finish that, *Multivariate Data Analysis* (Joseph Hair *et al.*) is fantastic.

Good luck!

Comment: I ordered Statistics in Plain English... I'll accept your answer when I get it on Thursday if I dig it as much as I think I will.

Comment: There is more than one book called "statistics in plain english". Do you mean the one by Timothy Urdan?

Comment: yes, the Urdan one, sorry for not being more specific

Answer (score 7):

This book is dynamite:
[George E. P. Box, Statistics for Experimenters: An Introduction to Design, Data Analysis, and Model Building](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471093157)

It starts from zero knowledge of Statistics but it doesn't insult the reader's intelligence. It's incredibly practical but with no loss of rigour; in fact, it underscores the danger of ignoring underlying assumptions (which are often false in real life) of common tests.

It's out of print but it's very easy to find a copy. Follow the link for a few options.

Comment: Thank you, Carlos, for the recommendation.  It is indeed a great read, despite (or perhaps because of) its age.  I'm especially impressed that the authors (Box, Hunter, & Hunter) appeal to *permutation* distributions, rather than arguing for normality, as the "ultimate" justification for the classical tests (t, F, etc.).

Comment: Looks like an excellent book! Going to buy a copy right now. =) Thanks for this, Carlos.

Comment: Book was first published in 1978, revised in 2005 and is currently in print.

Answer (score 5):

I am a big fan of [Statistical Models - Theory and Practice](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521671051) by David Friedman. It  succeeds remarkably well to introduce and motivate the different concepts of statistical modeling through concrete, and historically important problems (cholera in London, Yule on the causes of poverty, Political repression in the McCarty era..).

Friedman illustrates the principles of modeling, and the pitfalls. In some sense, the discussion shows how to think about the critical issues and is honest about the connection between the statistical models and the real world phenomena.

Comment: Freedman, not Friedman.

Answer (score 4):

The classic "orange horror" remains an excellent introduction: *Exploratory Data Analysis* by John Tukey.

[http://www.amazon.com/Exploratory-Data-Analysis-John-Tukey/dp/0201076160](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201076160)

Answer (score 3):

My favourite book on Statistics is is David William's [Weighing the Odds](http://amzn.to/aRoxQq). Davison's [Statistical Models](http://amzn.to/90gOnD) is good too.

Answer (score 3):

*Statistics as Principled Argument* by Abelson is a good side book to learning statistics, particularly if your substantive field is in the social sciences.  It won't teach you how to do analysis, but it will teach you about statistical thinking.

I reviewed this book [here](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/book-review-statistics-as-principled-argument-by-robert-abelson/)

Answer (score 3):

The best intro in my eyes is the following one:

> David Howell - Statistical Methods for
>   Psychology

It is the BEST in making statistical concepts understandable for non mathematicians so that they get the math afterwards!
Unfortunately it is updated every year and, hence, pricey.

Answer (score 2):

You might find useful this one: [The Elements of Statistical Learning: Data Mining, Inference, and Prediction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387848576)

UPDATE #1:

This book might be useful as well: [O'Reilly: Statistics in a Nutshel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596510497)l

Comment: May be a bit too academic for myself being such a beginner...

Comment: Elements of statistical learning is likely to prove very tough as an introduction.

Answer (score 1):

1. ***Wilcox, Rand R.*** - *BASIC STATISTICS - Understanding
   Conventional Methods and Modern
   Insights*, Oxford University Press,
   2009
2. ***Hoff, Peter D.*** - *A First Course in
   Bayesian Statistical Methods*,
   Springer, 2009
3. ***Dalgaard, Peter*** - *Introductory
   Statistics with R, Second Edition*, Springer, 2008

also take a glance at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192369/books-for-learning-the-r-language/2270793#2270793), though it's R-specific, there are plenty of books that can guide you through basic statistical techniques.

Answer (score 1):

As a biologist, I found the Sokal and Rohlf text to be quite readable, despite its voluminous-ness. It's not so great as a quick reference, but does walk one through statistical theory.

R. R. Sokal and F. J. Rohlf, Biometry the principles and practice of statistics in biological research, Third. (New York: W.J. Freeman and Company, 1995).

Comment: Now in fourth edition.

Answer (score 1):

An old favourite of mine as an introduction to biostatistics is Armitage & Berry's (& now Matthew's):

*Statistical Methods in Medical Research*

Answer (score 1):

Agresti & Finlay's Statistical Methods for the Social Sciences is quite good, though I'd like to believe there is a good open source alternative.  Is it wrong to use an amazon affiliate link here?