# The relationship between machine learning, data mining and statistical analysis?

Tags: machine-learning, multivariate-analysis, data-mining

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between data mining, statistics, machine learning and AI?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5026/what-is-the-difference-between-data-mining-statistics-machine-learning-and-ai)

How to compare 
machine learning vs. data mining?
data mining vs. statistical analysis?
machine learning vs. statistical analysis?

Comment: Is there anything you can add that would make this question less vague?  Such as the purpose or basis of the desired comparisons?

Comment: What is the differene between your question and this possible duplicate (http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5026/what-is-the-difference-between-data-mining-statistics-machine-learning-and-ai) ?