# what machine learning isn't statistical?

Tags: machine-learning, references

If I understand correctly, statistical learning theory is just *one* approach to machine learning,

What machine learning isn't statistical?

Based on my very limited understanding, I thought that things like PAC-learning or Empirical Risk minimization pretty much cover everything. Isn't statistics involved in all of this?

Is there any good source that clearly explains this?

**EDIT**

my comment below shows the answers I was looking for.

Comment: [The Two Cultures: statistics vs. machine learning?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6/the-two-cultures-statistics-vs-machine-learning)

Comment: [What is the difference between data mining, statistics, machine learning and AI?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5026/what-is-the-difference-between-data-mining-statistics-machine-learning-and-ai)

Comment: What would it mean to say something "isn't statistical"?

Comment: @RyanVolpi Well, why is there the need to call it statistical learning theory? As opposed to what?

Comment: I take that to be the way that statisticians claim such territory that might be more dominated by computer science.

Comment: Even for the autonomous vehicles, while that is not traditionally a statistics problem, if they’re using convolutional neural networks to analyze images (as I suspect they are), then they’re fitting regression coefficients.

Comment: Finally got my answer: Statistical learning can be contrasted with the probabilistic setting (frequentist vs. bayesian). Statistical approaches (SVM, Ridge/lasso, decision trees) try to find the one best hypothesis, optimization is used. 

In the probabilistic setting, we use Bayes rule for inference and need to keep track of all possible hypotheses (computationally expensive, explains use of MCMC or Gaussian distribution).

These two sometimes overlap (e. g. least squares viewed as MLE) but are fundamentally different.

Comment: Sources: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jFcYpBOeCOQ&list=PL05umP7R6ij2XCvrRzLokX6EoHWaGA2cC and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M2fUmhGTNrQ. Both lecture series are REALLY good.