# Good book on statistics

Tags: references

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What book would you recommend for non-statisticians?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/421/what-book-would-you-recommend-for-non-statisticians)

Hello all,

Which is a good book for self-learning of statistics? I tried the "Head first statistics" which starts very well, but when talking on t-distribution and some more complex issues, its quality degrades (just my opinion). Also, smth like "for dummies" might be too simplistic. I started now "Statistics in plain english", it might be a good startup for intuition, but I guess it will not suffice later on.

For example, I considered Feller's volumes on probability theory as a very good start for studying that domain. I am looking for similar consistent books in the domain of Statistics.

Thanks.

Comment: possibly related http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/421/what-book-would-you-recommend-for-non-statisticians

Answer (score 1):

If you liked Feller, then you definitely need to think about a real stats book. My suggestion as a self-learner at perhaps slightly less sophisticated level than you would be to look for Cox and Hinkley's "Theoretical Statistics". Very readable for a stats text. Not much, if any, in the way of problems sets, though.