# Book recommendations for Design of Experiments?

Tags: r, references, experiment-design

What are some good books on general design of experiments ?

Currently I am reading "Design and Analysis of Experiments" by Douglas Montgomery , it has too much mathematical details which are little intimidating. Can someone recommend a book which will give quick overview of the subject along with worked out examples (preferably in R language) ?

Comment: Similar (maybe a dup): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1815/recommended-books-on-experiment-design,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191004/learning-design-of-experiments/233956#233956,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a book by John Lawson [Design and Analysis of Experiments with R](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439868131) and he has developed a companion library called daewr. It's easy to follow. Good luck