# How to determine if the binary response was just randomly assigned and not due to any of the predictors

Tags: logistic, classification, boosting

I am practicing fitting models to data sets that I could find on Kaggle but I don't know how these data sets were generated.

I remember there was a data set I played around with in order to fit a classifier. I tried lgbm because one of the categorical predictors has large cardinality and I did not want to do one-hot encoding. I also tried just fitting lgbm to numerical features only. I also tried catboost and simple linear regression.

After trying these algorithms, I noticed that the logloss on the test data was more or less the same for each algorithm and for each specification (deciding which features to include/exclude, etc.). I also found out that if for each sample in the test set, if I assign the predicted probability of being in class 0 and class 1 to be the proportion of samples in the data set belonging to each class, the logloss of this model without any predictors is roughly the same as the logloss I obtained with the machine learning algorithms taking into account various predictors.

This is telling me that the features may be insufficient to explain the output since I'm doing as well without them. At the same time, since I don't know how the data set was generated, I am unsure if the response was just randomly assigned. Is there any other way to verify this?

Comment: This is what significance tests are all about.

Comment: I'm only familiar with significance tests for linear models. Is there one for other classifiers like decision trees?

Comment: The concept is completely general: you can *always* test whether data were randomly assigned (this is called the "null hypothesis") either by mathematically working out the distribution of your results or, in more complex cases, by generating many independent such datasets, applying your analysis procedure to each one, and examining the distribution of results.

Comment: I see. Do you have a reference you can point me to? A reference with an example would be very helpful. I'm not so familiar on this topic ...

Comment: I think I can do a goodness of fit test on the response variable and check that it is Bernoulli with probability $p$ where $p$ is a constant value. If the features indeed mattered, $p$ wouldn't be constant, it would be a function of the features. Do I have the correct general idea? Thanks!

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48347

Answer (score 0):

Testing whether the response is unrelated to the predictors is the same as testing whether the distribution of the predictors is the same between response categories (i.e., they both test whether the response is independent of the predictors). A test that was specifically designed for this situation is the **energy test for equal distributions**, described in [Rizzo & Székely (2016)](https://doi.org/10.1002/wics.1375), which contains R code to implement the test. If you reject the null hypothesis of the test, there is evidence that the distribution of the predictors is associated with the response category in some way (though it doesn't tell you *how*; that is the job of the prediction model).

Comment: This sounds interesting, but could you say a few words about how it might possibly work when one of the predictors has "large cardinality," as in the question?