# Problem books in introductory statistics

Tags: references

I'm going to teach an introduction to statistics course to college students with a little mathematical background. The syllabus of the course is mostly tables, graphics, means, medians, quartiles and some introductory dispersions concepts.

I would like to know if there is some book with a lot of exercises with solutions available to work with them.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What book would you recommend for non-statistician scientists?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/421/what-book-would-you-recommend-for-non-statistician-scientists)

Comment: I disagree this is a duplicate, since this course seems to target non-technical students and seems to be pitched at a lower level (equivalent to what would constitute a high school statistics curriculum in many countries). In fact **data literacy** may be a better term than "introductory statistics" for what the OP is looking for. The linked thread mostly concerns introducing statistics to technical professionals (who, in the words of the question, may seek to analyse time series or large data sets), a very different skill set to reading tables or knowing the difference between mean & median

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at [openintro.org](https://www.openintro.org/index.php) with practice labs in R

Comment: I'm sorry but what is R?

Comment: From the R project home page: 
R is a free software environment for statistical computing and graphics. It compiles and runs on a wide variety of UNIX platforms, Windows and MacOS. 
Used very extensively in the statistics fields and data science.

Answer (score 1):

I think this book pretty basic, there is no calculus or matrix in the book and it has almost every solution for the problems in book.
[image]