# Reference Books on Asymptotic theory of Statistics and Probability

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, references, asymptotics

Can anyone suggest me some good reference books on **Asymptotic Theory of Statistics and Probability** for students pursuing a post-graduate degree in Statistics ?

It would be very much helpful if the stated reference book(s) contained enough solved problems on the afore-mentioned topic, so as to get a good hold on the topic.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/421/what-book-would-you-recommend-for-non-statistician-scientists

Comment: [van der Vaart, A. W. (2000): Asymptotic statistics. Cambridge University Press](https://www.amazon.de/Asymptotic-Statistics-Statistical-Probabilistic-Mathematics/dp/0521784506/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1464626891&sr=8-1&keywords=asymptotic+statistics)

Comment: I am not a non-statistician @Elvis..

Also, I couldn't find any book on asymptotic theory on Statistics and Probability :-(

Comment: My bad! Well, if you want a reference book, the (above quoted) van der Vaart is excellent — but difficult.

Comment: That post was a long time ago but could you share the books you ended up using?

Answer (score 3):

As for probability, I would recommend: Borovkov, Probability theory
http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781447152002
It seems to be the only textbook that contains Stone's local limit theorems.

Comment: Sir, I specifically (and desperately.... to a great extent) require a book on Asymptotic theory of Statistics... the Statistics part is needed more than the Probability part.... :-(

Comment: There is a book by the same author https://www.crcpress.com/Mathematical-Statistics/Borokov/p/book/9789056990183 , but the price is unreasonable. This book is more devoted to fundamentals of mathematical statistics than to applications.